# Comparing two variables in a for loop

Tags: shell, for-loop

I need to make a for loop but I am relatively new to shell. I want the equivalent of:

```
For i = 1 to limit
```

As it would be in Visual basic, where 'limit' is a variable set to how long I want the for loop to go on for.

Comment: Sorry, just to make it clear this is for a shell script program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX way to do this without an external utility such as seq, is using a while loop:

```
limit=10
i=0

while [ "$i" -le "$limit" ]; do
   ...
   i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in $(seq 1 limit); do ...; done`

Answer (score 0):

If:

```
limit=10
```

Then in `zsh` use:

```
for i in {1..$limit}; do echo $i; done
```

In `bash` use the answers suggested by jordanm or Lars Kotthoff or use this:

```
for i in $(eval echo {1..$limit}); do echo $i; done
```

#### Edit

Both `bash` and `zsh` support this C-style type loop:

```
for ((i=0;i <= limit; i++)); do echo $i; done
```

Note, no need for `$` when within `(( ... ))`.

Comment: This will work in bash, zsh, and ksh but not csh, dash, or other POSIX-only shells.

Comment: The problem is that I want to be able to vary the upper limit.

Comment: @user1546083: I was testing this in `zsh` where `{1..$limit}` works. Now I noticed that an extra evaluation step needs to be added when doing this in `bash`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Thor - for bash, you shouldn't use eval, instead a C-style for loop is preferred. eg. `for ((i=0;i<=limit;i++)); do ...; done`. It will also work in bash, zsh, and ksh.

Comment: @jordanm: That's the only way to make `bash` expand `{1..$var}` :). But your `let` suggestion is much better, somehow I forgot about that. It should be added to one of the answers. Will you add it?

Comment: @jordanm: csh isn't a POSIX-compliant shell.